# React webpack / browserify "unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have this [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/color-picker-react) that I created and every time I try to include it to see if it works I get this error:

```
Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

I've used [react-starterkit](https://github.com/wbkd/react-starterkit) and included it in main.js like so

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ColorPicker = require('color-picker-react');
ReactDOM.render(<ColorPicker />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

then when i run `gulp` which runs `webpack` I get the error. Here's the `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports.getConfig = function(type) {

  var isDev = type === 'development';

  var config = {
    entry: './app/scripts/main.js',
    output: {
      path: __dirname,
      filename: 'main.js'
    },
    debug : isDev,
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }]
    }
  };

  if(isDev){
    config.devtool = 'eval';
  }

  return config;
}
```

I've tried everything I could think of and still can't get it to work. I'm not using ES6 anywhere and I've tried many different react starter kits but I just can't get it to work. Please help!!!

P.S. I am able to get the project to run when I clone it locally and build out `app.js` with `browserify` like so: `browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] app.js -o bundle.js`

Comment: Is your file extension `jsx`?

Comment: not originally, but if i rename them to `.jsx` it still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem you need to **remove** the line  `exclude: /node_modules/`  if you are not the author of the npm module (But you should go with another module).

The component `color-picker-react` doesn't seem to have a release build or script that compile the jsx. So you need to do it by your own and compile the jsx file on the fly using wepack.

Instead of just removing the `exclude: /node_modules/`

You can exclude all   `/node_modules/`  except the `/node_modules/color-picker-react` folder by using a regex pattern :

```
//will exclude all modules except `color-picker-react`
exclude: /node_modules\/(?!color-picker-react).*\//,
```

**EDIT Basics for creating a npm module**:

> A correct setup for a npm module is to add a prepublish script to
>   ensure compilation **happens automatically before uploading to NPM.**

Thus when you push your module to npm the users doesn't need to compile the module they can just require it.

Taking an example of a node_module: 
https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace/blob/master/package.json

The package.json file is saying which file is the entry point when you required the module

```
 "main": "lib/ace.js",
```

You can see in the github repository that the lib folder doesn't exist because added to the .gitignore but the line

```
  "prepublish": "npm run clean && npm run build"
```

is run **before uploading to NPM** so on the npm repository the lib/ folder exist and you can see it when you do `npm install --save react-ace` the lib folder appears in the `node_modules/react-ace/` folder

A great link that explains how to build npm modules in es6 for example  http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2015/10/authoring-modules-in-es6/

**EDIT explain what needs to be done on react-color-picker module :**

Sorry i didn't see that you was the author of the module so you **should go with the solution below**.

The react-color-picker for example doesn't have a prepublish script and the main file is index.js which is

```
var ColorPicker = require('./colorpicker.js'); // require a file with jsx will throw an error if not precompiled 

module.exports = ColorPicker;
```

So a syntax error is thrown.

To be able to use the npm module in your other applications :

1. Create a webpack config for the npm module to handle the conversion of your react component written using jsx (you can take some of the webpack configs of this module https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace set `libraryTarget: 'umd'` you module will be more easy to consume from various module systems (global, AMD, CommonJS).)
2. add a prepublish script that output a precompiled version of the color picker (`lib/pickedprecompiled.js`)
3. change the `main` to `"main": "lib/pickedprecompiled.js",`

Comment: if i replace `exclude: /node_modules/` and do `include: /node_modules/color-picker-react` then I still get the error. How should i have a release build or script? would that fix it?

Comment: You should remove the exclude line or find a regex that exclude all node_modules except the color-picker-react. I edited my answer for more clarity the simple solution is to remove the exclude: /node_modules/ line

Comment: Exclusion would work, but many other webpack projects are probably excluding all node_modules in their config too, so anyone using this npm module could run into problems. How do other npm modules handle this - do they precompile their JS?

Comment: Yeah they precompile their JS by adding a prepublish script to ensure compilation happens automatically before uploading to NPM, I edited my answer for more informations about that. So the color-picker-react is not well designed. There is no prepublish script for example to handle the jsx conversion

Comment: @cocoa I edited my answer on how to create and refactor the module. Sorry I missed the point that you were the author of the module so you should change your color-picker-react directly.